# How to use bypassSecurityTrustStyle correctly

Tags: angular

I am trying to work with some simple CSS and JavaScript examples in an Angular way.

The plain JavaScript way to change the background color on an element would look something like this:

```
this.container.style.backgroundColor = color;
```

The color is created randomly in JavaScript.
The template could look like this:

```
<div id="container"
  (click)="changeColor($event)"
  [style]="{'color': color}">
</div>
```

However, this will give the following error:

```
WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value [object Object] (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).
```

Using this function does not work:

```
this.color = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(this.color);
```

Creating a function to do it also does not work using this style [style.color]="transform(color)"

```
transform(value) {
   return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
}
```

I have created [a plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ssLM0myUsg8NDq4l3zJI?p=preview) to demonstrate this problem.

The correct behaviour using plain JavaScript is shown [in the first example on this page](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/triggering_animations_javascript.htm)

What is the correct way to do this?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The [example plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ssLM0myUsg8NDq4l3zJI?p=preview)
was using bypassSecurityTrustStyle correctly:

```
 this.color = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(this.color);
```

However, the template needed to set the value like this:

```
[style.background]="color"
```

Comment: I can't see `bypassSecurityTrustStyle` being used in the plunkr?

Comment: @Cocowalla, that's true.  I modified the plunker to user the correct style without bypassSecurityTrustStyle.  The above snipped shows how to use bypassSecurityTrustStyle correctly.  However, in this case, it is not necessary.  So, this answer is correct, but the plunker is demonstrating the correct use of the Angular style attribute for this case.

Comment: Downvoting because the Plunker is a lie. 

Comment: Correct example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-style-string-sanitizer?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `[styles]` or `[ngStyle]` like this :-

`<some-element [ngStyle]="{'font-style': styleExp}">...</some-element>`

or

`<some-element [styles]="myObj}">...</some-element>`

Where in the templates component myObj is `myObj = {color: 'red', font-size: '1.1em'}`

Docs for `[ngStyle]` [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgStyle-directive.html)

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in my question.  I was using [ngStyle] in the plunker.  I tried [ngStyle]="transform(color)" with that function being: transform(value) { return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value); }.  The value of color changes, but the CSS is not set.  The proper method is to set the style like this: [style.background]="color", no ngStyle needed.